# All referenced layouts and Buttons in ALL my java files all have warnings on them and I dont know how to fix it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, int

All layouts and button references mentioned in my java files all have warnings on them. The warning is always, button or layout cannot be resolved to a variable. I asked other developers for help on this and I was asked to remove the import android.R;. I was told it's not needed.

I did this and now all the R'S throughout my project have that same warning, I seemed to have traded one problem for another.

is there a way I can manually change the lines in the R.java file in gen/ because all layouts are in place in the layout folders and all buttons in the xml files have android:id:@+id/ I don't know what I have to do for Java to read its references so I can get past this hump.

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ZohanActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>  
        <activity
        android:name=".MacAttack"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".ConsultationReq"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Eclipse > Project > Clean?  If doing a clean doesn't work, check out the Problems tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all are you sure it's a warning? or is it an error?
Secondly, never modify the R file, because it is generated automatically. So all your modifications will be lost.

I would have to guess it's an error and not a warning. Here is what I propose to you:

1. Clean your project and rebuild
2. right-click the error, click on quick fix and choose "import package_name.R"